# Cloning a record using Clone() method in apex not working

Tags: apex, trigger, account, clone, app-development

I am trying to clone a record using below code in apex. A new record is getting created but all the fields are empty. How to clone a record with all the fields values populated from the source record in apex ?

Below is the code I tried.

```
List<Account> ExsFilterCloneRec = [select id, name from Account where name = 'TestAcc' ];

Account ExsRecSingle = ExsFilterCloneRec[0];

Account NewFilterCloneRec = new Account();
        
        NewFilterCloneRec = ExsRecSingle.clone(false, true, false, false);
        
        insert NewFilterCloneRec;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SObject's `clone()` method only copies fields that are in-memory.

That means you need to either set field values in Apex, e.g. `exsRecSingle.Description = 'some string';`, or explicitly query for your desired fields.

Querying all fields in Apex usually means building a dynamic SOQL query, fetching all of the fields from the SObject describe information (e.g. `Map<String, Schema.SObjectField> M = Schema.SObjectType.Account.fields.getMap();`), and looping over it to build the `SELECT` clause of your dynamic query.

Comment: I tried by querying another couple of fields. But those field values are not getting populated as well.

Answer (score 1):

You need to query all the field which you want to clone. I can see you are querying only Id and Name field. So probably your clone record gets name only in the New Cloned record.

Comment: I tried by querying another couple of fields. But those field values are not getting populated as well.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the suggestions.

Don't know why, but when I queried all fields and cloned from the anonymous window, field population from source record to destination record did not happen.

But when I did it in an Apex class, the fields got populated.